# Printing All A Linked Lists' Elements (C++)

Tags: c++, list, nodes

I am trying to use this function to print off of a linked lists' elements, but when I do it infinitely repeats the first item in the list. Any help is appriciated

```
}
cout << "Your list is: " << endl;

Node * start = head;
while (start)
{
    cout << start->data<<endl;
    start = head->next;
}

return menu(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (start)
{
    cout << start->data<<endl;
    start = start->next;
}
```

Will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is re-accessing the first list item on every iteration. You are not progressing to subsequent items at all.

You need to change this

```
start = head->next;
```

to this

```
start = start->next;
```